# what is default db of graphite

Tags: sqlite, graphite, graphite-carbon, whisper

I have read that Whisper db is the default db which graphite uses to store metrics. Default Graphite setup consist of whisperDb Ref [this](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage-backends.html?highlight=database). However i recently got confused to know that graphite-web uses sqlite db by default(Ref: [this](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-database-setup.html?highlight=database)).

Please reply to below query to avoid my confusion.
Does sqlite come by default in graphite-web component ? If yes then What type of data does it stores? If yes then Why this wep-app does not use whisper only ?

Answer (score 1):

Whisper is for storing the timeseries data where sqlite is used for storing profiles and preferences in the web portion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think sqlite is also used to store dashboards. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. Anything that's not time series data